# Why I have two legends ? How to fusion the legends ? Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm plotting 2 dataframes with this method:

```
df.plot(ax=ax, x='x', y='y', label = "first_df")
df2.plot(ax=ax, x='x', y='y', label = "second_df")
```

And I add some avxspan functions:

```
plt.axvspan(x, y, label = value)
```

Since that I have multiple avxspan and there are also dupplicated values, I am using this code to uniquely display the values.

```
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))            
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(),loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 0.8))
```

But when I display the legend, I have one legend for the dfs and an other for the avxspan functions. I think it is because I use `plot` for dfs and `plt` for axvspan, so I don't know how to fusion the legends.

**EDITH:**

I tried this with ax1 et ax2 for my dfs:

```
h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend((h1+h2), l1+l2, loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 0.8))
```

It's working but I have dupplicates in the legend, how can I remove it ?

Comment: `dataframe.plot` has a `legend` parameter accepting a bool btw.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of using `df.plot` which creates a legend whenever it's called, you can use `ax.plot`:

```
ax.plot(df['x'], df['y'], label='first df')
ax.plot(df2['x'], df2['y'], label='second df')

ax.legend()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after. Try include a minimal sample data and expected output.

Comment: the curves are functionnals, but to trace multiple axvspan functions I use a for loop for each value. But In the legend I have dupplicates

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, the legend is combined by plotting everything onto the same Axes including the avxspan with `ax.avxspan` and then running `ax.legend` to add the avxspan legend to the existing legend:

```py
import numpy as np   # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd  # v 1.2.3

# Create sample dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)
size = 30
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=range(size), y=rng.integers(0, 100, size=size)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=range(size), y=rng.integers(10, 50, size=size)))

# Plot data unto single Axes with combined legend using multiple plotting functions
ax = df.plot(x='x', y='y', label='first_df', figsize=(8,4))
df2.plot(ax=ax, x='x', y='y', label = 'second_df')
ax.axvspan(10, 15, label='span', facecolor='black', edgecolor=None, alpha=0.2)
ax.legend(loc='upper right');
```

[image: combined_legend]

Comment: thanks Patrick, but for the second df I have a different Y axis ans X axis are shared.

Comment: @ThonyNadhir Could you please edit your question to show more of the code you are using to generate the figure? It is currently not clear that there is a different y-axis, and the plotting functions for the dataframes both include `ax=ax` which does not match your last code snippet for the legend. I will be happy to edit my answer to provide a solution that works for you once you have provided more details.